# Execute process task fail to call child package

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, business-intelligence

I am trying to use execute process task call child package to process a file and I got a error message. The argument I have set as from previous step passed in variables.

When I execute the package, I got error message saying:

```
[Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" "
/FILE "\\serverIP\Work\SSIS\child_package.dtsx" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::controlCount].Properties[Value];"0" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::fileID].Properties[Value];"1" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::filePathName].Properties[Value];"\\serverIP\work\test.txt" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::archivePath].Properties[Value];"\\serverIP\work\archive\" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::stageID].Properties[Value];"10" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::MasterExceptionPkg].Properties[Value];"" 
/Conn OH_STAGE;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Server=serverIP;Database=OH_STAGE;Trusted_Connection=yes;" at "", The process exit code was "6" while the expected was "0".
```

My child package stored at location: \serverIP\Work\SSIS\child_package.dtsx

Argument:

```
/FILE "" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::controlCount].Properties[Value];"0" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::fileID].Properties[Value];"23" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::filePathName].Properties[Value];"" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::archivePath].Properties[Value];"" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::stageID].Properties[Value];"26" 
/SET \Package.Variables[User::MasterExceptionPkg].Properties[Value];""
```

Passed in variables values:

```
controlCount: 0
fileID: 1
filePathName: \\serverIP\work\test.txt
entityArchivePath：\\serverIP\work\archive\
MasterExceptionPkg: 
stageID: 18
```

Much appreciated if anyone can provide me some support. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your child package is success executed alone.
And try to add this package to master package.
Run VS as administartor